# Как получить указатель на данные в сокете udp?

Tags: linux, c, udp

Я делаю свой проект с использованием udp, и у меня появился вопрос, возможно ли в Linux без использования RAW сокетов при отправке или получении пакета получить указатель на буфер с данными, чтобы можно было их самому скопировать? Просто в моем проекте было удобно сначала прочитать по указателю первый 18 байт, а затем решить скопировать ли остальные 1434 байта. И с записью также. Грубо говоря мне нужно записать пакет по частям.

Comment: Мне кажется, что для чтения начала данных (с возможностью последующего чтения остатка пакета) вы можете использовать флаг `MSG_PEEK` в вызове [recv_from()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv), а запись по частям производит вызов [sendmsg()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto).

Comment: MSG_PEEK
Этот флаг заставляет выбрать данные из начала очереди, но не удалять их оттуда. Таким образом, последующий вызов функции вернет те же самые данные. Это из мануала и это не то, мне нужно чтобы второй вызов вернул следующие данные товоже пакета.

Comment: imho очевидно, что первым вызовом вы должны читать 18 байт, а вторым все 1452 (т.е. те же 18 (ну, это не слишком много -)) плюс остальные 1434 из того же пакета). Если во втором вызове вы не укажите MSG_PEEK, то все данные пакета сбросятся. Последующие вызовы будут брать данные уже из нового пакета. Или это не то, что вы хотите?

Comment: Я понял, спасибо, вернее я догадывался, но всё же хочется какуюто функцию найти для этого...

Comment: На уровне системных вызовов, вроде бы ничего такого, что вы хотите нет. Если какой-то юзер что-то такое и наваял, то похоже проще написать самому , чем найти (точно займет меньше времени, чем вы уже спрашиваете). (кстати, я бы еще потестировал, что 2 системных вызова дешевле по времени, нежели всегда читать эти полтора кило сразу)